# webpack replace values in code with values from json file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-intl

I am using [react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl) to localise my application. I have a json file that looks like this:

```
{
  "en": {
    "greeting": "Hello"
  },
  "es": {
    "greeting": "Hola"
  }
}
```

The code to display the message looks like the following. This all works and shows the translation as it should.

```
<FormattedMessage
    id={ 'greeting' }
    defaultMessage={ '__greeting__' }
    values={{
        greeting: messages.greeting
    }}
/>
```

Now comes the tricky part that I cannot figure out. I am using [string-replace-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader) to try and find the `defaultMessage` in my code. I then want to fill these with the corresponding English values in the json file. Obviously I can manually enter all of the `defaultMessages` however going forward this will be more cumbersome, so I am hoping that I can use webpack to do this for me.

```
{
   test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
   loader: require.resolve('string-replace-loader'),
   query: {
     search: '__',
     replace: \\ want to replace with the relevant key from the json file \\
    }
},
```

I have also looked at using the [html webpack plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin), however, this breaks the jsx.

in the webpack file

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  inject: true,
  meta: config,
  template: paths.appHtml,
}),
```

and then in the react code.

`defaultMessage={ <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.meta.en.greeting %>}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add all replacements using [multiple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader#multiple-replacement)

```
const defaultMessages = require('./path/to/messages.json').en

query: {
      multiple: Object.keys(defaultMessages).map(key => ({
       search: `__${key}__`,
       replace: defaultMessages[key]
      }))
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is the best option.